# xcode tab controller with customized graphics that won't load until first clicked

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, customization

I am customizing my TabBar Icons and I'm having a problem with the customized tab graphics not showing up until the first time they are clicked on, except for the first tab.  The setup is as follows  Entry->VC->Tab Controller->TabVC1->TabVC2->TabVC3->TabVC4->TabVC5.  What is the best way to get them showing up on first initialization of the tab controller.

** These attributes are set when I enter the tab controller (they work fine)

```
// Set background to white for the tab bar
UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabback.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];

// setting the selected color to blue
self.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];

// changing the tab bar text color
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,[UIFont fontWithName:@"Copperplate-Bold" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

** these are set in the individual TabVCs (they show up only after the first time their tab has been clicked)

```
// loading the custom icon for front and back
UITabBarItem *tabicon = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Daily" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Day.png"] tag:0];
[tabicon setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Day.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Day.png"]];
[self setTabBarItem:tabicon];
```

Comment: What method is the "loading the custom icon" code in?

Comment: `-(void)viewDidLoad` of the TabVC class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your tab bar controller should be your root view controller. That is, the rootViewController of your window. 
From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the
>   root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar
>   interface should never be installed as a child of another view
>   controller.

Also, since you call `self.tabBar` I get the feeling you are subclassing UITabBarController.
The documentation advice against this as well.

That being said, you can set up the tab bar items where ever you do your first appearance set up (the first code snippet).

For instance to alter the second view controllers tab item you would do

```
// loading the custom icon for front and back
UITabBarItem *tabicon = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Daily" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Day.png"] tag:0];

[tabicon setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Day.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Day.png"]];

UIViewController *second =  [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[second setTabBarItem:tabicon];
```

The point is that you need to set up the custom appearance before the tab bar view has appeared.

Comment: that did the trick, thanks for the answer!  Actually the order is Title Screen->Profile Selection Screen->Tab Controller->TabVC1->etc.  How would I make the Tab Controller my root view controller n this case?

Comment: Show the initial stuff modally is a good trick for this. For instance, in the `viewDidAppear` of VC1 you can instantiate your first screen from a nib or storyboard, then do something like: `[self presentViewController:theViewController animated:NO completion:nil]`. It will appear as this was shown first. When you are done, dismiss the modal view, and go back to the tab bar view.

Comment: Ok, good advice!!  Where would I put the `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` that would normally be in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` in the app delegate?  Otherwise, wouldn't you see the tab bar briefly before the other screen was loaded modally?

Comment: I don't think you will see it briefly when no animation is used. The problem is that you can't show it before your view hierarchy has been loaded, so I think you will have to wait for `viewDidAppear` to be called. But you can try loading it earlier, and see what the result might be. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Set the custom tabBarItem in your designated init method. This way it will get set when the controller is initialized and you wont have to wait until it is displayed for the first time to see your custom tabBarItem.

For example, here is an example in Swift, and where the controller is setup in a storyboard:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.tabBarItem = getTabBarItem(NSLocalizedString("Calendar", comment: ""), UIImage(named: "851-calendar.png")!)
}
```

Note that getTabBarItem() is a custom function of mine that returns a UITabBarItem.